# Getting a random number in MS Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, random

I am new to MS Visual Basic 2008. In fact, I am currently enrolled in the class. My final project for the class will generate random numbers within a range of numbers. For example, if I give the user five text windows to choose whether to input a number OR generate a random number, I will have a button called RANDOMIZE. Unfortunately, I do not know the line(s) of code for the random function.

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Just type `mathRand` **Tab** **Tab** for an example

Answer (score 3):

Try this method to generate a random number with a given min and max range:

```
Private Function GenerateRandomNumber(min As Integer, max As Integer) As Integer
   Dim random As New Random()
   Return random.Next(min, max)
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
 Dim i As Integer = GenerateRandomNumber(0,Int32.MaxValue);
```

Comment: @Chris: you're welcome, glad to help. Remember to use the green checkmark on the answer that helped you most. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I would add a Randomize() call before

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the documentation for `Randomize()` [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)